# Formula or pattern to calculate number of potential hexagons on a soccer ball pattern?

Tags: geometry

A standard soccer ball has 12 pentagons and 20 hexagons. I understand there will always be 12 pentagons due to Euler, but how many extra hexagons could you put on a soccer ball while keeping the hexagons all the same size. For example can I have 40 hexagons or 21 hexagons on a soccer ball? What is the pattern or formula to figure that part out.

Comment: Anything from 25 upwards, provided that you wish to be somewhat lenient about the "same size" requirement.

Comment: @IvanNeretin the 20 hexagons are currently the same size no? Can you double and make it 40... 60... 80... or does it not work that way? When you say 25 upwards you mean you can't really do 21-24... but everything above 25 should work?

Comment: Yes, the 20 are the same size; but that's where it ends. Yes, you can have 110 and more of them, and they will be _almost_ the same size, but not exactly so. Yes, everything above 25 should work.